# Pandas replace any integer with string using regex

Tags: regex, pandas, replace

struggling with something that is probably super basic, but I'm trying to replace some integers with string (using pandas & regex)

```
test = pd.DataFrame([14,5,3,2345])
test2 = test.replace('\d', 'TRUE', regex=True)
test2
```

When I run that, I expect to see: TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE, but instead I see exactly the same list:

```
test2
Out[93]: 
      0
0    14
1     5
2     3
3  2345
```

Am I missing something?  I thought '\d' is any numerical character?

Comment: Why are you trying this? Is your actual column a float or string? Do you have NaNs? What are you trying to do? Perhaps regex or replace _aren't_ the best options here.

Comment: It is an int64 column. After casting to string (based on answer posted below, it worked).  Is there potentially another way to do this?

Comment: Then can you not just do `df.astype(bool).astype(str)`?

Comment: Honestly it depends on what you want to do. How would you treat floating numbers with a fractional point? How would you treat whole numbers that are floats (eg 50.0) and how would you treat NaNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast the data to string and use a `^\d+$` regex to see if the whole string is composed of digits:

```
>>> test2 = test.astype(str).replace(r'^\d+$', 'TRUE', regex=True)
>>> test2
      0
0  TRUE
1  TRUE
2  TRUE
3  TRUE
>>>
```

The `^` matches the start of string, `\d+` matches 1 or more digits and `$` matches the end of string.

See [this **regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/mjzobK/1).

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that + the extra explanation of the regex!